# design is not properly coming in multiple screen support size in android devices

Tags: android

I have created layout,layout-large, layout-small layout-xlarge layout_xlarge-land but if i have  created emulator with giving resolution my design is coming good . but i have checked in devices  samsung galaxy tab 7 inch and samsung nexus s but my design in not properly coming can anybody tell what is problem? otherwise how to do?

This is my layout for large screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">    
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="Large Screen" />
<fragment class="com.hcl.gcm.fragment.MeetingFragment"
            android:id="@+id/meetingFrag"
             android:layout_marginTop="200dip"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dip"/>

<fragment class="com.hcl.gcm.fragment.MeetingRecieveFragment"
            android:id="@+id/receivingFrag"
             android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dip"/>

 <fragment class="com.hcl.gcm.fragment.ButtonFragment"
            android:id="@+id/btnFragment"
             android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: have you designed everything with dp

Comment: @Sadeshkumar periyasamy   yes

Answer (score 0):

The design for Multiple Screen size is always a difficult one in Android.

Some Guidelines I know:

1. Mostly Use Relative Layouts which suit any screen size.
2. If you design for different screen sizes, then using different size images are good.
3. Try to use Nine Patch PNGs for Button backgrounds.
4. Design a separate App if you develop App also for Tablets. Because Tablet users want rich graphic UIs.
5. Always check UI in multiple size emulators during development.

Comment: @sadeeshkumar Periyasamy whether dp will support multiple screen size?